# How to safely delete IIS7 Logs

Tags: iis-7

I've google'd for this without much luck.. but I'm looking for an manual (one time run, free) / open source way to safely clear iis logs from /inetpub/logs/logFiles

I've seen ppl refer to isslogs.com, I have no idea how reliable that is, but even then I dont want any kind of scheduled task nor wish to pay for something i'm not really going to use often

I just want a simple safe way to delete all logs from inside the multiple folders in /inetpub/logs/logFiles

Recommendations or walkthroughs on how these can be removed would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just delete them in Explorer or on the command line?

Comment: Explorer looks like alot of hard work with the number of different folders. No idea how to do from the command line. + I cant stop IIS so the active log, whichever that is cannot be deleted.

Comment: i think you need to clarify the question a bit. You will have to have some sort of scheduled task to keep removing them or they will just grow and grow (unless you turn logging off). While iis is running nothing will be able to get rid of the current log, so you will have to stop it. I would write a batch file to stop iis in the middle of the night, then remove the logs, then star iis again

Comment: As I said this is a one-time run only task. I dont want to schedule anything but wish to save myself a few hours doing this manually.

Comment: The point is that this *isn't* a one-time-only task. For the duration of your time administering this server, you will need to keep a lid on log-file growth. The easiest way to do that is with a scheduled task that does the same thing every day (or week, whatever.)

Comment: I'm doing it the one time, and nor am i a server admin. I have been delegated to do this by the powers that be. N quite simply I want to achieve it in the most risky free, future impact, or bite me in the @rse way in the future when the actual server admin returns.

Comment: Ah, I see. Whoever is the server admin is, isn't on top of things, then.

Comment: If you read the FAQ, you'd see why we're hammering the point home. We're assuming this system is yours to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script that deletes IIS logfiles older that 90 days

```
MaxDays = 90 
strComputer = InputBox("This script will delete IIS .log files over 90 days old "_ 
    & "from the machine you specify below.") 
wmiQuery = "Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem" 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery(wmiQuery) 
    For Each objItem In colItems 
        sWindowsPath = objItem.WindowsDirectory 
    Next 
Set objW3SVC = GetObject( "IIS://" & strComputer & "/W3SVC") 
    For Each objSite In objW3SVC 
        If objSite.Class = "IIsWebServer" Then 
            strLogDir = UCase(objSite.LogFileDirectory) 
                strLogDir = Replace(strLogDir,"%WINDIR%",sWindowsPath,1,1,1) 
                strLogDir = Replace(strLogDir,"%SYSTEMROOT%",sWindowsPath,1,1,1) 
                strLogDir = Replace(strLogDir,":","$",1,1,1) 
            objLogFolder = "\\" & strComputer & "\" & strLogDir 
            Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
            Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(objLogFolder) 
            Set colSubFolders = oFolder.Subfolders 
            For Each oSubFolder In colSubFolders 
                If InStr(UCase(oSubFolder),"W3SVC") Then 
                    For Each oFile In oSubFolder.files 
                        If InStr(LCase(oFile.Name),".log") Then 
                             If (Date - oFile.DateCreated > CInt(MaxDays)) Then 
                                oFSO.DeleteFile(oSubFolder & "\" & oFile.Name) 
                            End If 
                        End If 
                    Next 
                End If 
            Next 
        End If 
    Next 
MsgBox("All done.")
```

Comment: How do I use this, where do I execute the script?

Comment: Copy this into notepad and save it somewhere as script.vbs, or something like that To run it open the command prompt and type cscript script.vbs.

Comment: You save this as script.vbs and then you run it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the /S flag to del to force it to delete files in subdirectories. The /Q flag will prevent it prompting you - omit it if you want to be cautious. So something like:

```
del /S/Q logdir\*.log
```

If you want to also delete sub-directories, you can use 'rmdir'. it has the same two flag options.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked best for me.  Save as Retention.vbs and run or schedule.

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/managing-iis-log-file-storage

```
sLogFolder = "c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles"
iMaxAge = 30   'in days
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set colFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sLogFolder)
For Each colSubfolder in colFolder.SubFolders
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(colSubfolder.Path)
        Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
        For Each objFile in colFiles
                iFileAge = now-objFile.DateCreated
                if iFileAge > (iMaxAge+1)  then
                        objFSO.deletefile objFile, True
                end if
        Next
Next
```